# jstl loop to select proper value passed from form

Tags: jsp, loops, combobox, jstl

I'm attempting to have a combo box which defaults to the proper value passed in from a form.
it's basically a drop down of days along with a first and last of the month option..
here is the logic I have:

```
<select id="f9-1-13c" name="domNotify" value="${eBoxForm.domNotify}>
          <option value="-1"><fmt:message key="label.select_day" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>
          <option value="0"><fmt:message key="label.first" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>
          <option value="32"><fmt:message key="label.last" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="17">17</option>
          <option value="18">18</option>
          <option value="19">19</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="21">21</option>
          <option value="22">22</option>
          <option value="23">23</option>
          <option value="24">24</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="26">26</option>
          <option value="27">27</option>
          <option value="28">28</option>
          <option value="29">29</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
```

My question is how would I make a loop to select the proper value, including the first and last logic without having the if statement approach for each value.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you want to display that selected value when page first renders, if so you must have the selected value stored and returned from server

In Servlet or whatever MVC framework you use

```
request.setAttribute("selectedDay", selectedDay);
request.setAttribute("daysInMonth", daysInMonth); //daysInMonth is a List/Collection of all days
```

In JSP

```
    <select id="f9-1-13c" name="domNotify" value="${eBoxForm.domNotify}>
      <option value="-1"  ${selectedDay == -1 ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="label.select_day" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>
      <option value="0"  ${selectedDay == 0 ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="label.first" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>
      <option value="32"  ${selectedDay == 32 ? 'selected' : ''}><fmt:message key="label.last" bundle="${i18nForm}" /></option>

   <c:forEach items="${daysInMonth}" var="day">
            <option value="${day}" ${day== selectedDay ? 'selected' : ''}>${day}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```